# Does Civi still support the ability to set a specific start date for recurring contributions?

Tags: recurring-contributions

Civi used to have a feature that allowed me to set a start date other than "today" when I set up a recurring contribution with a credit card. We did not have this field active on our website, only staff used it to tweak recurrings as necessary. After we upgraded recently to 4.6.2 I can no longer find that field. I accessed it by clicking on Submit a Credit Card Contribution button. I don't recall exactly where it was placed, only that I used it several times and it was a great feature for us.

Am I missing something? Did this feature get moved? Or should I go to Civi's forum and ask for it to be re-instated?

Answer (score 1):

This issue appears to have been resolved. When we upgraded to Civi 4.6.10 the missing fields have reappeared. These fields were very useful, not having them was problematic, and I am very happy that I can use them again.

Answer (score 1):

Setting a start date in the future for a recurring payment series has only recently garnered core support (i.e. the ability for a payment plugin to tell core that it supports a future start date). So in any particular CiviCRM install, you may find:

1. If your payment processor doesn't support future start dates, it won't show.
2. If your version of Civi is too old, it won't show.
3. If you've got an extension that solves this problem before Civi core did, it might show anyway.

More details here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15555

Answer (score 0):

I ran a test for this actual situation.  In Civi 4.6.8, the field exists, but using the PayPal payment processor, it seems to be ignored.

The test occurred on 09/18/2015.  The start date was 09/24/2015. But the transaction was executed on 9/18/2015.  While the transaction was pending, the received date reflected 09/24/2015.  This was changed when the transaction was executed.

Looking at the code for PayPal, the start date is set up as:

```
$start_time = strtotime(date('m/d/Y'));
$start_date = date('Y-m-d\T00:00:00\Z', $start_time);
```

and passed via:

```
 $args['profilestartdate'] = $start_date;
```

This looks like a bug.