# How to set a recurring membership start date to be 1st of the month

Tags: civimember, recurring-contributions

We have Authorize.net and Stripe as payment processors. We'd like to have recurring memberships run on the 1st of the month. I see under contributions there looks to be the potential to set it but that isn't working. ([Does Civi still support the ability to set a specific start date for recurring contributions?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3328/does-civi-still-support-the-ability-to-set-a-specific-start-date-for-recurring-c)) There is no such setting for membership.
[image]

How can we pass this data to e.g. Authorize.net? Is it technically possible to have custom code achieve this and has anyone done so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is available thru the [Stripe integration](https://docs.civicrm.org/stripe/en/latest/) as a new feature discussed in issue [#199](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/-/issues/199). For reference, it started with the  [6.5 release](https://docs.civicrm.org/stripe/en/latest/releasenotes/#release-65).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Auto-recurring memberships are triggered by the corresponding recurring contribution, so what you need is:

1. A payment processor that supports future dates for recurring contributions.
2. A way to restrict which dates are allowable.

For 2., the functionality is built into the iATS Payments extension, and also in my extension here:
https://github.com/adixon/ca.civicrm.contributionrecur

I'm not sure if my implementation in that custom extension will work with Authorize and/or Stripe, but you could try it. Those processors might need a small patch for it to work.